# What script is the next newsletter?

Tags: url

The link is something like:

I receive a lot of newsletters on my email and all of them have this link format so i am guessing its a newsletter script.

?utm_source=xxxx&utm_campaign=03a7a847cc-13_5LeiBagdad_22LeiMagicRoyal3_3_2011&utm_medium=email

what is the name of the script ? any ideas ?

Thanks

Comment: Please add more context so other people can have a stab at guessing what you are trying to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like Google Analytics tracking code to me.